# How can I remove the category meta from the grid section of my homepage using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have inspected the page (http://hemptoday.net) using Developer Tools in Chrome. Using Custom CSS plugin for WordPress, I entered the following code to try and remove the category meta for the grid widget on the homepage (where there are 16 stories in grid format below 4 in list format at the top of the page).

Code I entered in Custom CSS is as follows:

```
.entry-meta .mh-fp-grid-widget.clearfix { display: none; }
```

Using Custom CSS, I have been able to customize a few things, but this one is a little more complicated.

Comment: The CSS you have above looks for an element with both mh-fp-grid-widget and clearfix classes that is also a descendant of an element with the class entry-meta. Looking at your code I don't see that hierarchy.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the response, I appreciate it. I already tried that code without the .clearfix at the end as well. Of course, it didn't work that way either. I also tried .entry-meta { display: none; }, but that hid the category meta for every item on the page, which makes sense. I am trying to figure out how to specify just those grid items, and remove the category meta from them. I will figure it out eventually. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just `.mh-fp-grid-widget.clearfix`?

Comment: @j08691 Do you mean without ".entry-meta" before it? No, I did not. ".entry-meta" has to be there, right? That is the element I am trying to hide from the grid items. Thanks.

Comment: So the 4x4 grid of stories isn't what you want to hide? If it's the meta tags within the grid, try `.mh-fp-grid-widget.clearfix .entry-meta`

Comment: @j08691 Thanks so much. That worked. I guess I had it backwards with the `entry.meta` first. Can you suggest a good guide or place to learn more about css (and any other coding languages that may be helpful, perhaps html and php)?

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the selectors backwards based on your HTML.

Try: `.mh-fp-grid-widget.clearfix .entry-meta`